# Sum of n i.i.d Beta-distributed variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume that I have $n$ variables that are each $X_i \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha, 1)$ distributed (with the same $\alpha$, i.i.d.).

Is there anything known about the distribution of the sum $Y=\sum_i X_i$?
I've tried to understand the works of Pham-Gia, but couldn't entirely grasp them. He seems to use some modified generalized Beta $B^*$.

An approximation is also fine with me, as long as I can compute some quantiles. I'm mostly interested in quantiles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your $Y$ will have mean $\frac{n\alpha}{\alpha+1}$ and variance $\frac{n\alpha}{(\alpha+1)^2(\alpha+2)}$

If you want a reasonable approximation other than a normal distribution with that mean and variance, you could say that $\frac{1}{n}Y$ has mean $\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1}$ and variance $\frac{\alpha}{n(\alpha+1)^2(\alpha+2)}$ and then find a Beta distribution with those moments that would give you $\alpha'=\alpha\frac{\alpha n+2n-1}{\alpha+1}$ and $\beta'=\frac{\alpha n+2n-1}{\alpha+1}$.

The density function for this approximation to $\frac{1}{n}Y$ would then be $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha'+\beta')}{\Gamma(\alpha')\Gamma(\beta')}x^{\alpha'-1}(1-x)^{\beta'-1}$ on $[0,1]$ and the density function for the corresponding approximation to $Y$ would be $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha'+\beta')}{n\Gamma(\alpha')\Gamma(\beta')}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^{\alpha'-1}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)^{\beta'-1}$ on $[0,n]$.

As an example, consider $\alpha=3$ and $n=2$.  You get a mean of $\frac32$ and variance of $\frac3{40}$, and for the approximation you get $\alpha'= \frac{27}{4},\beta'= \frac{9}{4}$.  In the following plot, the black curve gives the actual density, the red curve the stretched-Beta approximation and the blue curve the normal approximation.  The red curve is not too far away in this case.

[image]

Similarly the cumulative distributions look like the next chart and you can see that the quantiles of the red stretched-Beta approximation are much closer than the quantiles of the blue normal approximation here.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I will assume $X_i$ independent in this post. To get a feel for the problem, recall the special case of uniform distribution, corresponding to  $\alpha=1$, i.e. $\mathrm{Beta}(1,1) \stackrel{d}{=} U(0,1)$.

The sum of $n$ iid uniform distribution was studied by J.O. Irwin and P. Hall, and the result is known as [Irwin-Hall distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution), aka uniform sum distribution.

Already for $n=3$ the distribution density of the sum of three standard uniform variables approximates normal quite well:

[image]

The same approximation will work well for larger values of $n$ in your case as well. To write it out we need to compute mean and variance of the sum:
$$
  \mu_n = \mathbb{E}(\sum_{k=1}^n X_i) = n \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1} \qquad
  \sigma_n^2 = \mathbb{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^n X_i) = \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{Var}(X_i) = \frac{n \alpha}{\alpha+2} \frac{1}{(\alpha+1)^2}
$$

Thus the quantile function approximation is:
$$
   Q_n(q) \approx  n \frac{\alpha}{\alpha+1} + \frac{1}{\alpha+1} \sqrt{ \frac{n \alpha}{\alpha+2} } Q_{\mathcal{N}(0,1)}(q)
$$

For $n=2$ CDF can be worked out exactly, and can be inverted using numerical algorithms:

[image]

---

**Added**: The normal approximation can be truncated to $(0,n)$ interval to improve accuracy:
$$
   Q_{Y_n}(q) = \mu_n + \sigma_n Q_{N(0,1)}( (1-q) \Phi(-\mu_n/\sigma_n) + q \Phi((n-\mu_n)/\sigma_n) )
$$

Comment: "The same approximation will work well for larger values of n in your case as well" But probably not so well, is $\alpha$ is very different from 1. I would go this route, though, is $n$ is large.

Comment: I need $\alpha$ to be different from 1, and $n$ to be larger than $2$.
I'm particularly interested in $\alpha = .5$ (as this occurs in my situation for Euclidean distance, a prime example of an $L_p$ norm - $1/p$ is actually my equation for $\alpha$), and I'm interested in the development of this distribution when I increase $n$. Of course I do expect it to approximate a Gaussian distribution for large values of $n$; at the same time I know it will never be _exactly_ Gaussian, as negative values are not possible here.