# Sum of Beta Random Variables

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Supose I have $I$ independently (but not necessarily identically) distributed beta random variables, $X_i = \text{beta}(\alpha_i,\beta_i)$, for $i=1,\dots,I$.

Is there a known distribution for the sum of these r.v.s, $Y=\sum_i X_i$?

Furthermore, is there a known distribution for the mixture of these r.v.s, as in $Y=\sum_i \omega_i X_i$, where $\sum_i \omega_i = 1$?

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85535/sum-of-n-i-i-d-beta-distributed-variables

Comment: Not in closed form.  There isn't even a closed form expression for the PDF of the sum in the case $n=2$.